# Apple Mail keeps crashing frequently after RAM problem

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, crash

**Update**: while waiting for a response I managed to solve the matter, first by running mail from a different account (it worked flawlessly); and second by running Onyx - it has the feature of rebuilding mail envelope index - which resolved whatever issue my system had. Anyway.

Thank you for the helpful suggention.

---

I am having a problem with Apple Mail. Following a bad RAM problem on my PowerMac G5/10.5.8 Apple Mail 3.6 started to crash frequently, shortly after I open it, or whenever I try to do anything with it, for example when selecting a message or attempting to send a mail. Each time the spinning beachball appears, and mail crashes.

Restarting, permissions repairs and the use of Disk Utility, DiskWarrior and TechTool Pro hasn't helped.

I have included a crash log below:

```
Process: Mail [782]
Path: /Applications/MAIL/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier: com.apple.mail
Version: 3.6 (936)
Build Info: Mail-9360000~1
Code Type: PPC (Native)

Parent Process: launchd [66]


Date/Time: 2015-02-13 21:42:38.367 +0100
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)

Report Version: 6

Anonymous UUID: A75D0409-433A-44F1-9D38-E34AED349277


Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ce6f7b80

Crashed Thread: 11

Thread 11 Crashed:

0 ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 0x93acd610 CSStoreGetUnit + 56
1 com.apple.LaunchServices 0x920c55d8 CSStringCopyCFString + 92
2 com.apple.LaunchServices 0x920e2acc CSStringBindingCopyCFStrings + 120
3 com.apple.LaunchServices 0x920e2864 _LSCopySchemesAndHandlerURLs + 156
4 com.apple.MessageFramework 0x00960b2c +[URLifier _urlMatchesForString:startIndex:matches:] + 1820
5 com.apple.MessageFramework 0x00960024 +[URLifier urlMatchesForString:] + 348
6 com.apple.mail 0x0004cc44 0x1000 + 310340
7 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x940159a8 __invoking___ + 168
8 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x94015230 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 128
9 com.apple.MessageFramework 0x009f49ec -[MonitoredInvocation invoke] + 392
10 com.apple.MessageFramework 0x009f461c -[InvocationQueue _drainQueue] + 656
11 com.apple.Foundation 0x90ad9d84 __NSThread__main__ + 1004
12 libSystem.B.dylib 0x93438f70 _pthread_start + 316

------

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ce6f7b80
Crashed Thread:  10

Thread 10 Crashed:
0   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x93acd610 CSStoreGetUnit + 56
1   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x920c55d8 CSStringCopyCFString + 92
2   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x920e2acc CSStringBindingCopyCFStrings + 120
3   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x920e2864 _LSCopySchemesAndHandlerURLs + 156
4   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00960b2c +[URLifier _urlMatchesForString:startIndex:matches:] + 1820
5   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00960024 +[URLifier urlMatchesForString:] + 348
6   com.apple.mail                  0x0004cc44 0x1000 + 310340
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x940159a8 __invoking___ + 168
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94015230 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 128
9   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x009f49ec -[MonitoredInvocation invoke] + 392
10  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x009f461c -[InvocationQueue _drainQueue] + 656
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x90ad9d84 __NSThread__main__ + 1004
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93438f70 _pthread_start + 316
```

Comment: Your update to your question would make a correct answer. It would be useful to others too. It confirms that your library was corrupted by `Mail` running on a faulty RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Since you had a faulty RAM, the first target of corruption is the whole filesystem. It is a good point to have eliminated this possibility of huge trouble.

If your problem does only appears within `Mail` this could mean that one of the files `Mail` had to write back was corrupted (in RAM).

To confirm this hypothesis:

1. make a backup
2. quit `Mail` and make a local backup of your Mail library (the following are shell commands to type within `Terminal`):

   ```
   cd ~/Library
   mv Mail Mail.backup
   ```
3. start `Mail`, create you a minimal account configuration
   and send yourself an E-mail

   If `Mail` doesn't crash, the problem stands within one of your Mail library file

   If `Mail` still crashes, report it.
4. quit `Mail` and put back in place the library you backed up at step 2:

   ```
   cd ~/Library
   rm -rf Mail
   mv Mail.backup Mail
   ```

If step 3 confirms that the problem stands within your Mail library,
and if your mailboxes aren't too big, you could then make a rebuild of them:

1. launch Mail
2. select

   ```
   Mailbox > Rebuild
   ```
3. be patient, don't corrupt its rebuilding task, open the activity window:

   ```
   Window > Activity
   ```